# Spinner values are not storing in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I have an application to store data in firebase using textviews and spinners, values of textviews are saved accurately but spinners values are not showing in database, some random values are stored instead.
[My firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxM5z.png)

This is my candidate1 class which write data to firebase:

```
    package package_name;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    public class candidate1 extends AppCompatActivity{

        private EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;
        private Spinner  spinner1 , spinner2;
        private Button submmit;
        DatabaseReference ref;
        FirebaseDatabase database;
        candidate candi;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_candidate);
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

            editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2)

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.program, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.session, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            ref = database.getReference("candidate");
            candi = new candidate();
            submmit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submmit);
            submmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            addCandidate();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(candidate1.this,"Data inserted successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
            });
        }
        private void getValues(){
            candi.setName(editText1.getText().toString());
            candi.setRegNo(editText2.getText().toString());
            candi.setCatagory(editText3.getText().toString());
            candi.setProgram(spinner1.toString());
            candi.setSession(spinner2.toString());
        }
      private void addCandidate(){
          ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("candidate").push();
          String name= editText1.getText().toString().trim();
          String regNo= editText2.getText().toString().trim();
          String catagory= editText3.getText().toString().trim();
          String session= spinner2.toString().trim();
          String program= spinner1.toString().trim();
          String id=ref.push().getKey();
          if((id.equals(id))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(regNo))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(catagory))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(session))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(program))) {
              getValues();
              ref.child(id).push();
              ref.child("Name").setValue(name);
              ref.child("RegNo").setValue(regNo);
              ref.child("Category").setValue(catagory);
              ref.child("Program").setValue(program);
              ref.child("Session").setValue(session);         
              Toast.makeText(candidate1.this,"Datainserted...",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }else{
              Toast.makeText(candidate1.this,"Data insertion Failed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
    }
```

I used two spinners **program** and **session** and define their array in **string.XML**. Please help me I don't know where i did mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any mistake 
For getting values from the spinner you need to use

the following thing:

```
user.setProblem(spinner_problem.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
```

you have to use getSelectedItem() this will call the values that you have stored in your string.xml file in this the selected item will be displayed.